# How to set QtWebEngine Content-Security-Policy (CSP) to default-src?

Tags: qtwebengine

i have a qtwebengine view inside my app, and I'm having issues with apple music regarding the CPS, for some reason, it is set to script-src

```
https://music.apple.com/us/browse:143 Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: 
"script-src 'self' https://*.apple.com blob: 'sha256- ....  'unsafe-eval'". 
Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ....., or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

I don't want to use the --disable-web-security flag to disable CSP, i want to change it to default-src

does anyone know how to do this?